# connecting java application with rds on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

i have created EC2 instance and rds instace on aws linux. I have created database and added few tables and connected with aws rds instance. and included database connectivity part in tomcat server.xml file as below. but it is not working. please help me.

```
<Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="true" description="MySQL database."
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
global="jdbc/myDatabase" maxIdle="10" maxTotal="50" maxWaitMillis="30000" name="jdbc/myDatabase"
password="test123" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://project.cous2mhgi4.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/myDatabase"
username="tester"/>
```

Do we need to install any drivers on aws linux to connect with database?

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: the same code in tomcat server.xml connects to aws rds instance from my local eclipse. but when i make tomcat server.xml change in linux ec2 instance it doesn't connects to database. do i need to install some jdbc driver on my aws linux instance.

Comment: But is there an error, and if so what is it?